# Dropdown menus- Javascript vs CSS only-which to choose for desktop-mobile compatibility

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I've read this thread, 
[Dropdown menus by CSS or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219292/dropdown-menus-by-css-or-javascript)

but see that there are conflicting opinions over use of CSS only vs javascript for dropdowns.

Is the only argument in favor of using CSS only to accommodate people with javascript turned off?
Are there any other considerations?

Which method is more forgiving in a site that must work on desktop and most mobile browsers (iOS, android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop down menus tend to be designed for pointing devices. It is very rare to find one that can handle linear (e.g. keyboard tabbing through items) or touch interaction (although you can degrade gracefully if the top level items link to pages that provide onwards navigation).

I doubt it is possible to get one that works well for linear or touch without JavaScript.

Comment: One trick is to have the menu driven by media queries and/or something like Modernizr, so that different elements are exposed to touch devices. Of course Modernizr is JavaScript, and there's no good way to detect touch devices with just media queries (I don't think).

Comment: I'll have to spend more time browsing on my ipad to see how others have approached this problem.

Answer (score 0):

And ideal solution for this is one that uses both. So it works for people without java script and it is improved for people with javascript (animation....)

Like you say it depends on the requirements and to be honest if the device targetted support CSS3 you can probably do a cool animated one in CSS only.